# How do I render errors in the template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I am following this guide: http://ember.vicramon.com/chapters/all

So far so good! However, I was trying to get Ember validate based on the validation definitions of my Rails model. So far so good here too.

My code follows the same approach as instructed: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html or not?

This is what I have so far:

**app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :json

def create
  product = Product.new product_params

  if product.save
    respond_with :api, :v1, product
  else
    render json: { errors: product.errors }, status: 422
  end

  # respond_with :api, :v1, Lead.create(lead_params)
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/controllers/products_new.js.coffee**

```
App.ProductsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend
  actions:
    createProduct: ->
      product = @store.createRecord 'product', @get('fields')
      product.save().then =>
        @transitionToRoute 'product', product

# app/serializers/product_serializer.rb
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :amount_in_cents, :status, :errors
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/templates/products/new.js.emblem**

```
article#product
  h1 New Product

  ul
    each errors.messages in error
      li = error

  /* {{#each errors.messages}} */
  /*   <div> */
  /*     <p class="label label-danger">{{this}}</p> */
  /*   </div> */
  /* {{/each}} */

  form
    fieldset
      dl
        dt: label Name:
        dd: view Ember.TextField value=fields.name

      dl
        dt: label Description:
        dd: view Ember.TextField value=fields.description

      dl
        dt: label Amount in cents:
        dd: view Ember.TextField value=fields.amount_in_cents

      dl
        dt: label Status:
        dd: view Ember.TextField value=fields.status

    fieldset.actions
      input type='submit' value='Create Product' click="createProduct"
```

I submit the form with an with empty field, and Firebug console returns: `422 Unprocessable Entity`

Which is normal, but the errors dont show on the template... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow developer, Alex Speller, helped out with this and suggested I do:

```
  product.save().then =>
    @transitionToRoute 'product', product
  , =>
    @set 'errors', product.get('errors')
```

in **app/assets/javascripts/controllers/products_new.js.coffee**

Seems to work!